# VBA - On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

Tags: vba, error-handling

I have a simple question about error-handling in VBA.
I know how to use the `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` statement but instead using my own code at the specified label, I would rather use a prefabricated VBA-message. Something like this in C#:

```
catch(Exception ex){
    Console.Writeline(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your error handler code your can access the `Err.Number` and `Err.Description`. The Description in the error message you would have seen without error handling, so is the equivalent of `ex.Message` in your code sample.

Answer (score 3):

Create an ErrorHandler Module and place this sub in it.

```
Public Sub messageBox(moduleName As String, procName As String, Optional style As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbCritical)
    MsgBox "Module: " & moduleName & vbCrLf & _
        "Procedure: " & procName & vbCrLf & _
        Err.Description, _
        style, _
        "Runtime Error: " & Err.number
End Sub
```

Call it from anywhere in your project like so.

```
Private sub Foo()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'do stuff

ExitSub:
    ' clean up before exiting
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    ErrorHandler.messageBox "ThisModuleName","Foo"
    Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```

I use a module scoped constant to hold the module name.
Modify to suit your needs.

Comment: You're welcome. Error handling in vba is a pain. Lots of repetitive code. It's ugly. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thank @DanWagner. If only I could automatically get the procedure name at runtime....