# Error Handling - Where to enter 'Exit Sub'?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have the below code which simply opens a file. If there file does not exist in teh lcoation specified then I require an error message to appear. The trouble I am having with the below code is that when the file does exist it opens, enters 'Hello' into cell A1, however the MsgBox still appears. I think I have the Exit Sub in the wrong place??

```
Sub Test()

Dim Location As String
Dim File1 As String
Dim Err1 As String

On Error GoTo Err1
  Location = "S:\HRIS\Restricted\Information Services\Regular Reports\DRS _   
    Automation\" & Format(Date, "DD.MM.YYYY")
      File1 = "\Test.xlsx"
        Workbooks.Open FileName:=Location & File1

Range("A1").Value = "Hello"

Err1:
  MsgBox "Could not Locate " & Location & File1
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: You need an Exit Sub before Err1.... See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23688126

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move `Exit Sub` before `Err1` label:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim Location As String
    Dim File1 As String
    Dim Err1 As String

    On Error GoTo Err1
        Location = "S:\HRIS\Restricted\Information Services\Regular Reports\DRS Automation\" & Format(Date, "DD.MM.YYYY")
        File1 = "\Test.xlsx"
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Location & File1

    Range("A1").Value = "Hello"

    Exit Sub

Err1:
      MsgBox "Could not Locate " & Location & File1

End Sub
```

Comment: I Realised as soon as I posted. Thanks for your help.